# Deleting rows with same foreign key but different primary key without affecting each other

Tags: c#, linq, delete-row

Here, I want to delete the information for CustomerId(1) with OrderId(2) & OrderId(3) without affecting the CustomerId(1) with OrderId(1).

Is there any procedure for doing so? [img: Database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ke4xJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerId = 1 AND OrderId IN (2,3)
```

Comment: You're welcome, if you find the answer useful, you can mark the answer as accepted. I also recommend you make a tour using https://stackoverflow.com/tour to utilise the benefit of the platform.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

```
where customerid=1 and (orderid=2 or orderid=3)
```

which will work exactly as your question is worded...

Or, depending on what you are really asking:

```
where customerid=1 and orderid <> 1
```

which will delete everything except rows where custid is 1 and orderid is not 1

Comment: Thank you. But in case of fetching the data from database based on the passed CustomerId from the view to controller, I'll not be knowing what the expected OrderIds are. It will fetch all the data with CustomerId (1) & delete it. Pardon me if I failed to make you understand.

Comment: Delete from Order where customerid=1 and (orderid=2 or orderid=3)